# Installing SharePoint 2010 in Microsoft VPC (Windows 2008 Server) Vs Upgrading MOSS 2007 in same server?

Tags: installation, windows-server-2008, sharepoint-2010

I am aware of the upgrade options for SharePoint 2010

http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/details.aspx?displaylang=en&FamilyID=e8b66eb3-27c7-4a39-a2e1-3e7d18b12ee1

The above talks more of a Production Deployment.

And i have seen so many Windows 7 VHD boot for SharePoint 2010.

Would like to hear options for the MS VPC with Windows 2008 Server+MOSS2007 towards upgrading to SharePoint 2010.

The above is for personal lab and exercises.

Please share your views (URLs, Forum Discussion) pros, cons.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

MS VPC doesn't support 64 bit client, so it's not an option for running SharePoint 2010

The main options available are:

1. On your physical machine
2. VHD boot
3. Hyper-V
4. VMWare

1 and 2 only support one server installations
3 doesn't work well on laptops
So my preferred choice is 4

But it very much depends on your machine and needs